# Como funciona a indexação com os buscadores utilizando Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, front-end, seo

Como os buscadores indexam o conteúdo exibido com angular?

Pesquisei a respeito e verifiquei que aparentemente o Google lê *Javascript* [segundo esta matéria](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html).

Mas isso é realmente verdade?

Estava navegando e olha o que encontrei no site oficial da globo:

[image: Site da globo mostrando as tags do angular ao invés do conteúdo]

Acredito que essa sintaxe seja do Angular.
Se o Google não lê JS como corrigir esse tipo de erro ?

Comment: É verdade, mas ele não consegue simular todas ações possíveis. Funciona se o programador souber o que está fazendo, o que é raro. E quando sabe, ele entende que algumas coisas não poderão ser solucionadas, aí ou escolhe tirar aquilo ou aceitar que perderá a indexação (a não ser que use uma forma de escape para o conteúdo ser indexado independente do AngularJS).

Comment: Não vejo como erro. Se ao invés de *expression* fosse `ng-model`, seria uma solução?

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que pesquisei, o Google está começando a interpretar SPAs em javascript. Mas existem casos de SPAs que ainda não são reconhecidas pelo buscador do Google, pois realizei testes com o Search Console e aparecia somente as Angular Expressions.

Para solucionar o meu problema com este SEO, busquei ferramentas na Web que realizam **HTML Snapshots**, e quando algum buscador acessa sua página, o servidor redireciona para o solicita para esta ferramenta somente o HTML de sua página e o entrega para o buscador. Com isto, seu site será interpretado não somente pelo Google, mas também pelos outros buscadores.

Aqui estão duas ferramentas que realizam bem este trabalho, e existem versões gratuitas:

- [Prerender.io](https://prerender.io/)
- [Seo4Ajax](https://www.seo4ajax.com/)