# Paginas com conteúdo carregado dinamicamente por angular tem problema com indexação no Google?

Tags: angularjs, ajax, seo

Tenho uma página hoje que já está em produção e acessível a qualquer pessoa pelo Google aonde seu conteúdo é totalmente carregado do Servidor e renderizado.

Fiz um upgrade nela e agora o seu conteúdo será carregado e manipulado via **ANGULAR + AJAX**

Isso pode me custar pontos no Google?

Posso ter problemas indexação/ranqueamento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu respondi uma questão similar aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/159045/54272

Então, caso já exista um sistema de HTML Snapshots em seu site, seus links, meta-tags e conteúdo sejam os mesmos de antes deste upgrade, talvez o Google não lhe tire posições, e talvez até melhore o posicionamento.

Recomendo que faça testes no [Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=pt-BR) para ver como o Google visualiza a sua página atual.

Comment: Muito obrigado, vou dar uma olhada.